# How to deploy kubernetes 1.6 without kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm a bit confused about what version of kubernetes I need and what method to use to deploy it.

I have deployed 1.5 the manual way. But there is a fix we need (PR-41597). This fix doesn't seem to have been merge in 1.5 but it is in 1.6.

But I can't find any way to install 1.6 without kubeadm. The documentation clearly states that kubeadm should not be used in production. And the kubeadm way does not allow for upgrades anyway. So I would prefer to stay away from kubeadm.

So I either have to get that fix merged in 1.5 or find a way to install 1.6 without kubeadm. Am I missing something here? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of ways to install Kubernetes 1.6:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides

For example, CoreOS's CloudFormation installer supports 1.6: https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-aws.html#announcement-to-regular-users-of-kube-aws

As does Canonical's Juju templates: https://jujucharms.com/canonical-kubernetes/

If you need more specific assistance, please share more about your target environment (cloud/bare metal, OS, etc.).

A fairly low-level set of instructions can be found in https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way; this may help you to tailor your own setup process.

For CentOS specifically, your best bet might be [Kargo](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kargo). This doesn't yet support 1.6, but it is active, so it should receive a 1.6 patch soon.

Comment: Thanks @Symmetric, Could you please help to get more information on setting up Kubernetes 1.6 on Centos 7 OS  without Kubeadm .

Comment: Sadly it looks like CentOS has not got much love @ShreeTiwari. I added a link to a low-level guide that might help.

Comment: @ShreeTiwari note that Kargo now supports k8s 1.6 with Centos 7.

Comment: Thanks the hard and long way to install kubernetes it's what I was looking for.